# How to open an existing folder/file with the terminal on a mac?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to programing and have difficulty working with terminal. I want to know how to pull up an existing file I already created before? Im using Ruby/Rails.

Comment: Are you trying to access a file from a Rails app or just from the command line?

Comment: Please post what you've already tried.

Comment: I figured it out. cd /folder/file name thanks!

Comment: yes, I was trying to open it from a Rails app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change your current directory

```
cd /folder/folder/
```

To move back one directory

```
cd ..
```

To list files in a directory

```
ls
```

To open files

```
open filename.ext
```

Comment: If your in the rails console look at 'load' for running .rb files you've created.

for more tips on using the rails console http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to the people who responded.
My question can be answered very simply.
To get into any directory type in Terminal cd and the name of the file.
As long as the file exists inside the directory I'm in, it is easy as that.